# Current item cannot be removed from the list because there is no current item

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I wrote this code to delete the selected record:

```
Dim Str As String = "DELETE FROM TableName WHERE ID=" & IDTextBox.Text & ""
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        If Sqlcon.State = ConnectionState.Open Then Sqlcon.Close()
        Sqlcon.Open()
        With cmd
            .Connection = Sqlcon
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = Str
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
            .Dispose()
        End With
        Sqlcon.Close()
```

But I get this Error:
(Current item cannot be removed from the list because there is no current item)

I couldn't find the problem!

Comment: That doesn't sound like database error but it may be lost in translation. Have you checked if a record with that Id exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to validate the input in the text box to be sure it is a number. (I guessed that the ID field is a number) `TryParse` will return `True` or `False` and if `True` it fills the second parameter with the number.

It is a good idea to separate your database code from your user interface code.

Both Commands and Connections need to be disposed so they should be declared locally in a `Using` block.You should never have to check `ConnectionState` because the connection is always in the method where it is used. Wherever the connection is declared elsewhere, delete it.

You can pass the `CommandText` and `Connection` directly to the constructor of the Command. `CommandType.Text` is the default so you don't have explicitly assign it.

To avoid sql injection and assure the correct type is presented to the server **ALWAYS** use Parameters.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Id As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(IDTextBox.Text, Id) Then
        DeleteRecord(Id)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid ID")
    End If
End Sub

Private OPConStr As String = "Your connection string."

Private Sub DeleteRecord(id As Integer)
    Dim Str As String = "DELETE FROM TableName WHERE ID= @ID;"
    Using SqlCon As New SqlConnection(OPConStr),
            cmd As New SqlCommand(Str, SqlCon)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id
        SqlCon.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using 'disposes the command and closes and disposes the connection
End Sub
```